# Facebook login manager "expression is ambiguous" error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm trying to build an IOS game with Swift and I've hit an issue while adding a custom Facebook Login button.

I have the following code inside a touchesEnded function:

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
            loginManager.logIn([ .PublicProfile ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
                switch loginResult {
                case .Failed(let error):
                    print(error)
                case .Cancelled:
                    print("User cancelled login.")
                case .Success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                    print("Logged in!")
                }
            }
```

My problem is that [ .PublicProfile ] creates a build error saying "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context".

Now this is weird given that the code is literally copied from Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login).

How can I fix this?

### Extra information

Here is the login function from the Facebook API

```
  public func logIn(_ permissions: [ReadPermission] = [.publicProfile],
                viewController: UIViewController? = nil,
                completion: ((LoginResult) -> Void)? = nil) {
let sdkPermissions = permissions.map({ $0.permissionValue.name })
sdkManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: sdkPermissions,
                 from: viewController,
                 handler: LoginManager.sdkCompletionFor(completion))
  }
```

and here is the "ReadPermission" Enum

```
public enum ReadPermission {
  /// Provides access to a subset of items that are part of a person's     public profile.
  case publicProfile
  /// Provides access the list of friends that also use your app.
  case userFriends
  /// Provides access to the person's primary email address.
  case email
  /**
   Permission with a custom string value.
   See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions for full list of available permissions.
   */
  case custom(String)
}

extension ReadPermission: PermissionRepresentable {
  internal var permissionValue: Permission {
    switch self {
    case .publicProfile: return "public_profile"
    case .userFriends: return "user_friends"
    case .email: return "email"
    case .custom(let string): return Permission(name: string)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, sounds like an ambiguity between Swift versions. Which version of iOS are you compiling for? Which Swift version?

Comment: IOS 10 and Swift 3

Comment: The API was updated to Swift 3 in september according to the change log

Comment: And you're double sure the version you're using locally is up to date?

Comment: I downloaded it about 5 hours ago... I'll see if i can work out how to check for updates to be sure

Comment: Alright, never mind that then 

Comment: yeh, the Facebook pods are all up to date

Comment: glad to see it's not just me that's stumped by this. I've applied to join the Facebook developer group... hopefully someone on there can help me and i/they can answer this question soon 

Comment: You could try changing the first letter of the enums to lower case. It would probably give you a warning if that was the problem, but it's worth a shot. Posting the documentation/declaration of the specific functions being called would also help.

Comment: where would i find these enums?... inside the loginManager class?

Comment: Found it. I have updated the question with the function and Enum from the API @PEEJWEEJ

Answer (score 3):

The enum starts with lower case now. (`case publicProfile`) so you need to use `.publicProfile` rather than `.PublicProfile`, that may also be true of the loginResult, but I would have to see it in order to know.

Comment: I had the same problem you fixed it. Thanks a lot ! Note : .Failled, .Cancelled and .Success have to be in lowercase too